# If município!=municipalidade then why município==municipality?

Tags: etimologia, tradução, tradução-inglês, localização

I am trying to figure out which is the most indubious translation of [*município*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/munic%C3%ADpio) or [*concelho*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/concelho) with these meanings:

> - Circunscrição territorial em que se exerce a jurisdição de uma vereação.
> - Subdivisão do distrito administrativo composta de uma ou mais freguesias. = CÂMARA, MUNICÍPIO

Municipality seems to be the [most common translation](http://www.linguee.pt/portugues-ingles/traducao/munic%C3%ADpio.html) but it resembles a lot [municipalidade](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/municipalidade) which I preferably want to avoid, since it can be [interpreted as a township](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipalidade) and may have [several meanings depending on the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Township_%28disambiguation%29).

County on the other hand, resembles a lot more [*condado*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/condado) than [*concelho*](http://www.linguee.pt/portugues-ingles/traducao/concelho.html) and towns are [not necessarily municípios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Portugal). Finally, a city in some cases has an exact match with a *município* in Portugal...

Therefore, in a formal/specification document, if I am to use a translation of *município* or *concelho* with a maximum of a couple of English words to define it solely as a territory composed by a group of parishes (*freguesias*), which word(s) should I use?

It would also be interesting to know the origin of the word *município* since Portuguese and Spanish seem the only languages to use this word and even [google translates it to *ciudad*](https://translate.google.com/#pt/es/munic%C3%ADpio), when in Spanish the word [*municipio*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipio) exists.

Comment: More than once you say you're worried about which Portuguese words certain English words *resemble.* In general this should be irrelevant, as the English translation is for English speakers, not Portuguese speakers. Is there something specific about the audience you're translating for that would make this more relevant? Could you add this to your question?

Comment: @DanGetz I was curious and wanted to be more certain about the most popular translation before using it. The audience is worldwide so I wanted to specifically refer to the territory itself and not to the group of people who govern it. Perhaps you didn't check the links but I found other words that could possibly refer to this territory more precisely, such as "township". If found though it has more ambiguous meanings (depending on the country it's used) than "municipality". So with [Jacinto's answer](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1513/156) I will be more confident in using this word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Municipality*** is the best equivalent to both ***município*** and ***municipalidade***. No need to be troubled by this, because one of the meanings of *municipalidade* is *município*.

The Oxford Learner’s dictionary defines [***municipality***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/municipality?q=municipality) as:

> (1) a town, city, or district with its own local government; (2) the group of officials who govern it.

Definition (1) is the primary meaning of the Portuguese word ***município***, whereas (2) is the primary meaning of the Portuguese word ***municipalidade***. Quoting from the Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa:

> ***Município***. (Do latim *municipium*) **(1)** *Histórico* Cidade conquistada, no tempo dos romanos, com direito a administrar-se pelas suas próprias leis, e cujos habitantes gozavam dos direitos civis de cidadania romana. **(2)** Circunscrição territorial administrada por uma vereação, por uma câmara municipal, superintendida por um presidente. **(4)** *Brasil* Circunscrição administrativa autónoma do Estado, governada por um prefeito e uma câmara de vereadores.
>
> ***Municipalidade*** **(1)** Conjunto de pessoas eleitas pelo povo de um município para administrar os seus interesses = Vereação. **(4)** Circuscrição territorial em que uma vereação exerce a sua jurisdição = Concelho, Munícipio.

*Município* comes straight from the Latin *municipium*, and, ultimately, so does the English word *municipality*. DACL's definition (1) basically explains what a *municipium* was, but for more you can always count on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipium).

Comment: Thanks for the details, I also found in your Oxford link that there's a link to the their other English "advanced dictionary" which has a little more about its etymology: «late 18th cent.: from French *municipalité*, from municipal from Latin municipalis (from *municipium* ‘free city’, from *municeps*, *municip-* ‘citizen with privileges’, from *munia* ‘civic offices’) + *capere* ‘take’».

Comment: It makes sense that the English sould come from French. The Wikipedia article says quite a bit about the roman *municipium* too.